# Polygon rendering: Clockwise vs counterclockwise?

Tags: rendering, polygon

I'm making a rendering engine (mostly for personal use). I already know which way the polygons are and all that, but what I want to ask is which way is better? It seems that counterclockwise ordering is the most common, but clockwise is also used. Personally I prefer clockwise, because it just makes more sense when I am visualizing it in my head, but are there any sort of advantages to counterclockwise?

Answer (score 0):

Polygon orientation/direction (clockwise vs counterclockwise) is totally dependent on the display software's configuration - specifically whether it uses a positive Y axis (Y values increasing upwards) or a negative Y axis. Reversing the display's Y axis will change clockwise polygon orientation to counterclockwise and vice versa.

What's much more important to polygon rendering is to define one or more **filling rules**. The 2 most widely used filling rules are EvenOdd (sometimes called Alternate) and NonZero (sometimes called Winding).

Here's a link to an explanation on polygon filling using [SVG](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/painting.html#FillRuleProperty), and another link to polygon filling using [OpenGL](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/chapter11.html), and yet another using [Quartz 2D](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/drawingwithquartz2d/dq_paths/dq_paths.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001066-CH211-TPXREF101).